# Get from SourceB any element with an ID in SourceA

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have been trying to build what may seem like a strange joining method for two models in two different DB, you can query first one and then return small list of id's to search in another db. everything is working ok bar one or two things, I cannot do the Id list subquery using lambda functions, I have the Id selector function that links off generic but in the where clause it will now work as I do not know who to link source type object to the passed function for Id so the `.Where(TSource => idlist.Contains(Idselector)` the example code is below as far up to where it breaks because of the `List.Conatins` code. If anyone can help would be greatly appreciated as I am stook

```
public static Foo JoinTwoModels<T1,T2>(
           DbSet Dbs1,
           DbSet Dbs2,
           Expression<Func<T1, object>> Id1,
           Expression<Func<T1, dynamic>> Selector1,
           Expression<Func<T1, bool>> Search1,
           Expression<Func<T2, object>> Id2,
           Expression<Func<T2, dynamic>> Selector2)
        {
            var Output1 = Queryable.OfType<T1>(Dbs1);

            var Output2 = Queryable.OfType<T2>(Dbs2);

            List<dynamic> Result1 = Output1.Where(Search1).Select(Selector1).ToList();

            List<object> idList = new List<object>();

            PropertyInfo p1 = Result1[0].GetType().GetProperty("Id");

            foreach (var o1 in Result1)
            {
                idList.Add(p1.GetValue(o1));
            }

            //Query result entries into db
            List<T2> Result2 = Output2.Where(idlist.contains(Id2)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Context;
    public string Data;
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Context;
    public string Data;
}

public static IEnumerable<TOutput> JoinTwoModels<T1, T2, TIdent, TOutput>(
    IEnumerable<T1> sourceA,
    IEnumerable<T2> sourceB,
    Func<T1, TIdent> idSelectorA,
    Func<T2, TIdent> idSelectorB,
    Func<T1, TOutput> selectorA,
    Func<T2, TOutput> selectorB)
{

    var queryA = sourceA
            .Select(x => new {Value = selectorA(x),Id = idSelectorA(x)});

    var queryB = sourceB
            .Select(y => new {Value = selectorB(y),Id = idSelectorB(y)})
            .Where(y => queryA.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(y.Id))
            .Select(y => y.Value);

    return queryA.Select(x => x.Value).Concat(queryB);
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sourceA = new List<Foo>() {new Foo() {Context = 2, Data = "I'm a Foo"}};
    var sourceB = new List<Bar>() {new Bar() {Context = 2, Data = "I'm a Bar"}};

    var Output1 = sourceA.AsQueryable();
    var Output2 = sourceB.AsQueryable();

    var results = JoinTwoModels(
        Output1,
        Output2,
        (Func<Foo, int>) (x => x.Context),
        (Func<Bar, int>) (x => x.Context),
        (Func<Foo, string>) (x => x.Data),
        (Func<Bar, string>) (x => x.Data));

    foreach (var item in results)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

What you wanted wasn't quite clear; so above I'm selecting all the items from Source-A (of type Foo) and Source-B (of type Bar) that share a common Context (id), and returning them in a converted common type.

You can simplify this down if you only want the values from b, to:

```
var queryA = sourceA.Select(idSelectorA);

var queryB = sourceB
        .Select(y => new {Value = selectorB(y),Id = idSelectorB(y)})
        .Where(y => queryA.Select(x => x).Contains(y.Id))
        .Select(y => y.Value);

return queryB;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help David, you are correct that I wanted to join the two results together on Id, but I wanted the flexibility to select multiple/varying fields each time hence the dynamic function return, I am only intermediate so not sure but is yours fixed to classes fixed value/id properties or is this dynamic in number fields returned? also this seems to be linq-to-object IEnumberable queries, will this work just the same for IQueryable to DB? thanks once again

Comment: Firstly, the IEnumerable won't run until you iterate over the results; so I think you're safe to run IEnumerables on-top of a IQueryable (although I've never tried). As for dynamic; dynamic moves problems from compile-time to run-time. I would try to avoid it and be strongly typed... Foo, T1, T2 and TOutput can be anything. But I imagine your database will have two columns, ID and VALUE and that the type of VALUE doesn't change from row to row.

Comment: Also don't mix up two problems; Go grab the values with matching ID; that will return as an IEnumerable... convert that into a Query and run your data field selection on top of it. i.e. You could have T1 and T2 as IQueryable. etc...

Comment: Thanks, I have multiple values/fields I wanted to return (and select dynamically) from each source but can appreciate it is not god practice to use dynamic and debug in runtime. Is it not bad for performance to run my data field selection on a select few fields on top of query returning whole object dataset? sorry for asking so many questions, you've been most helpful

Comment: Yes, this bit **quearyA.Select(x => x).Contains(y.Id)** will run the query on databaseA each time. if you pull it out and resolve it, it'll only run once. i.e. .ToList(). But now, you are resolving the query inside something else. SO, break it up. Don't have one method that does two things.

Comment: That's great, thanks for clarifying will work on implementing a version of your code using this methodology into my app, thanks again

Comment: Does this answer your question then? If so can you mark it? :)